# Is It possible to programmatically resize a column [ngx-datatable]

Tags: ngx-datatable

Is it possible when using the **ngx-datatable** to programmatically resize a column?
Any help will be appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll find your answer on this post https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/193

And there is a method call adjustColumns() on the ngx-datatable you can find the documentation of the code there : https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/90ad41d56ec58522b7793aaa6d1f9265ff7ed024/src/components/datatable.component.ts#L165

Hope this would help you! :)

Comment: unfortunatly It dit not help. I thought/hoped that there may be an event 'resize' on top of the column that I could programmatically use as there is for sort or click